# Starscream framework and ios app with cocoapods (Xcode V9.2)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, character

I have been tasked to compile the ios app... sounds simple enough right?
I ended up getting errors that Starscream framework could not be found. So I went and installed cocoa pods. I made sure everything was linking and I am now further than I was.

When I run the app on a simulator and I try to sign in with the username and password I get this error "Cant save password : unhandledError(-34018)

When I try login with a secondary set of logins it says logging in and immediately then says "Signed out."

[Also get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkLJj.png)

Comment: show your code..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkLJj.png